# Teradata - Invalid time zone specified while converting time zones

Tags: teradata

I am trying to do a join between a date column and the current date in a local timezone using:

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
a
join b on (a.country_id  = b.country_id)
and date_column =  (Current_date at b.capital_timezone)
```

b.capital_timezone has values like Europe Central, Europe Eastern,GMT+4, GMT+5:30 etc.,

I get an error saying - 'Invalid time zone specified'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following syntax. Also avoid null values in timezone column.

```
Current_date at TIME ZONE coalesce(b.CAPITAL_TIMEZONE,'GMT')
```

According to [Teradata docs](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ch07.077.013.html), GMT+5:30 seems to be an invalid time zone value. Convert it to a valid value.

From the docs:

**Strings that do not follow separate DST and standard time zone displacements**

- 'GMT'
- 'GMT+1'
- 'GMT+10'
- 'GMT+11'
- 'GMT+11:30'
- 'GMT+12'
- 'GMT+13'
- 'GMT+14'
- 'GMT+2'
- 'GMT+3'
- 'GMT+3:30'
- 'GMT+4'
- 'GMT+4:30'
- 'GMT+5'
- 'GMT+5:30'
- 'GMT+5:45'
- 'GMT+6'
- 'GMT+6:30'
- 'GMT+7'
- 'GMT+8'
- 'GMT+8:45'
- 'GMT+9'
- 'GMT+9:30'
- 'GMT-1'
- 'GMT-10'
- 'GMT-11'
- 'GMT-2'
- 'GMT-3'
- 'GMT-4'
- 'GMT-5'
- 'GMT-6'
- 'GMT-6:30'
- 'GMT-7'
- 'GMT-8'

**Strings that follow different DST and standard time zone displacements**

- 'Africa Egypt'
- 'Africa Morocco'
- 'Africa Namibia'
- 'America Alaska'
- 'America Aleutian'
- 'America Argentina'
- 'America Atlantic'
- 'America Brazil'
- 'America Central'
- 'America Chile'
- 'America Cuba'
- 'America Eastern'
- 'America Mountain'
- 'America Newfoundland'
- 'America Pacific'
- 'America Paraguay'
- 'America Uruguay'
- 'Asia Gaza'
- 'Asia Iran'
- 'Asia Iraq'
- 'Asia Irkutsk'
- 'Asia Israel'
- 'Asia Jordan'
- 'Asia Kamchatka'
- 'Asia Krasnoyarsk'
- 'Asia Lebanon'
- 'Asia Magadan'
- 'Asia Omsk'
- 'Asia Syria'
- 'Asia Vladivostok'
- 'Asia West Bank'
- 'Asia Yakutsk'
- 'Asia Yekaterinburg'
- 'Australia Central'
- 'Australia Eastern'
- 'Australia Western'
- 'Europe Central'
- 'Europe Eastern'
- 'Europe Kaliningrad'
- 'Europe Moscow'
- 'Europe Samara'
- 'Europe Western'
- 'Indian Mauritius'
- 'Mexico Central'
- 'Mexico Northwest'
- 'Mexico Pacific'
- 'Pacific New Zealand'
- 'Pacific Samoa'